# Trying to skip python UDF on Nonetype attribute (null) in PYSPARK

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have pyspark dataframe with Firstname and Middlename columns . Middlename column has null values in it.

customer_df=

```
FName Middlename 
Avi   null
Chec  Bor-iin
Meg   null
Zen   Cha-gn
```

I have written UDF to strip hypens

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf, upper, lit, when
replacehyphens = udf(lambda string_val: string_val.replace('-',''))
customer_df=customer_df.withColumn('Middlename',
when('Middlename'.isNull,lit('')).otherwise
(replacehyphens(col('Middlename'))))
```

I am getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isNull'

What am i missing here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `'Middlename'.isNull`, you are calling `isNull` method on a string instead of the column object. You need **`col('Middlename').isNull()`** or **`df.Middlename.isNull()`**; Or you can use `regexp_replace` method instead of creating a `udf`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace
df.withColumn('Middlename', regexp_replace(df.Middlename, '-', '')).show()
+-----+----------+
|FName|Middlename|
+-----+----------+
|  Avi|      null|
| Chec|    Boriin|
|  Meg|      null|
|  Zen|     Chagn|
+-----+----------+
```

To replace `null` with empty string, use `na.fill('')`:

```
df.withColumn('Middlename', regexp_replace(df.Middlename, '-', '')).na.fill('', 'Middlename').show()
+-----+----------+
|FName|Middlename|
+-----+----------+
|  Avi|          |
| Chec|    Boriin|
|  Meg|          |
|  Zen|     Chagn|
+-----+----------+
```

---

If you have to use a udf, make sure you do the null check inside the `udf` to avoid the `Nonetype` error:

```
replacehyphens = udf(lambda s: s.replace('-', '') if s else '')
df.withColumn('Middlename', replacehyphens('Middlename')).show()
+-----+----------+
|FName|Middlename|
+-----+----------+
|  Avi|          |
| Chec|    Boriin|
|  Meg|          |
|  Zen|     Chagn|
+-----+----------+
```

Comment: Hi Psidom,  when i use column                                                                              customer_df = customer_df.withColumn('MiddleName',when(col('MiddleName').isNull,lit('')).otherwise(stripsc(col('MiddleName')))) . I am getting TypeError: condition should be a Column.The reason I am trying to create udf is because , I would be adding more special characters into it based on incoming dataframe

Comment: Did you miss the parenthesis after `isNull`? notice it's `isNull()`.

Comment: Ahh , got it ! Thank you !